# How can I force fetchmail to re-fetch mail in Gmail's inbox?

Tags: linux, gmail, smtp, fetchmail

My Linux server fetches mails from gmail and sends it to a Domino server process (SMTP). No problem there.

The issue is that mails were fetched *before* the Domino server was started, so there was no SMTP connection available. It takes a while before the SMTP port becomes available.

I can see which mails are missing, and I moved them from the Trash/Bin in Gmail to the Inbox. Those mails weren't fetched. Then I marked them as unread. Nothing happened. I even cleared out the .fetchids file in Linux. Added fetchall as well, to no avail.

Question is: how can I tell fetchmail to re-fetch these missing mails??

Comment: There are two mechanisms to re-fetch Gmail messages: both work with Thunderbird/POP3, but I have no idea if they are applicable to `fetchmail`. (1) Prepend `recent:` to the log-in user name: this down-loads again all messages from the last 30 days; delete those you don't need. (2) If it's only a few messages, use the web interface to open a message and using the three-dot menu click on `Show original`, then on `Download original`: for TB I save as `Title.eml`, which can be opened and copied to any e-mail folder, including Inbox. You'll need to determine if `fetchmail` can use either technique.

Comment: Thank you. I think that `fetchmail` doesn't have these options, but I'll look into this further. I'm happy to say that my mails arrived after all. How exactly I don't know yet. Still, the theoretical case seems interesting, how to get skipped mails.